# How do I aggregate all my threads line in dashboard report graphs into a single line

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, test-report

When I generate dashboard report in Jmeter, the graph have several lines of various thread groups on the graphs showing various statistics of the test. But I want a single line in the graph showing the overall performance of the  test. Anybody has any suggestions????

Answer (score 1):

As per current JMeter version (JMeter 4.0) it is something which is not supported.

The options are in:

1. Go for [Composite Timeline Graph](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/) where you can combine as many charts into single one as you want. You can install Composite Timeline Graph using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Composite Timeline Chart]
2. Use a 3rd-party results analysis tool like [BM.Sense](http://sense.blazemeter.com/) which provides Composite Timeline Analysis tab, basically the same as in point 1 but with extended functionality, via fancy web interface and having possibility to export the chart into professionally-looking PDF

   [image: BlazeMeter Sense Composite Timeline]